# I have wrote an ng new ang-routing command to create a new angular project inside my folder and it shows the following error

Tags: angular, npm

```
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2fbuild-angular: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\ezhil\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-28T15_18_13_595Z-debug-0.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the angular cli and still same error occurs. I request anyone to provide me a proper solution for this.

Comment: try to clean cache  npm cache clean -f

Comment: What command are you running? Are you sure AngularJS applies, in addition to Angular (two different frameworks)? Please share all relevant versions (Angular CLI version, OS/environment, package.json if applicable, etc)

Comment: the command i wrote was

ng new ang-route

I use Angular

Angular CLI: 16.2.8
Node: 18.18.0
Package Manager: npm 10.2.1
OS: win32 x64(Windows 11)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the node_modules and as @Hezy Ziv mentioned, clear the npm cache then re-install